# Why does ICE needs both-ways signaling?

Tags: webrtc

To establish WebRTC connections the ICE protocol is used with a signaling server which must send messages in both directions. I wonder why after the initiator sent its offer and candidates to the other participant, the participant needed to send back its answer and candidates using the signaling channel in the other direction. Cannot the participant open the connection to the initiator using candidates from both sides and send back its answer using the open connection?

I started reading [ICE RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245) and the only relevant part I found is in section `5.2` where the initiator must take the controlling role and nominates candidate pairs. But it does not explain why the other could not initiate connection.

To give some background, I am trying to build a webapp for which I want users to establish WebRTC connections without using a signaling server. I thought of having the app to generate a URL including the offer and candidates and providing this URL to other participants through other medium like instant messaging. The issue I got is that the participant need to send back its answer and candidates using the same medium, which is not practical. In the end I will go for a signalling server but I wonder the technical reason.

Comment: maybe this will help you https://github.com/cjb/serverless-webrtc

Comment: Your example makes me realize offer and answer include ICE candidates and I can reduce sharing URL, thank you. But I still wonder why it requires to send the answer using the signaling channel (here IM)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that if caller is behind public IP or Full Cone NAT(in this case, router connection mapping needs not to be timed out).
You can able full fill above conditions rarely.

What's the problem with other NAT types?
For example , PRC(port restricted cone) NAT won't allow you to receive a packet from a IP:Port , if you didn't send any packet to that IP:Port before. So callee will never able to send you a packet.

So if callee sends her candidates list to you . you can send some dummy data(with low TTL) to her IP:Port to fool your PRC NAT (now it allow incoming packets from callee's IP:Port as it sends a packet to that IP:Port before).

To know more about different types of NAT:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation

http://think-like-a-computer.com/2011/09/16/types-of-nat/